# SQL query filtering returnd rows by conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I need help with filtering result rows returned by a query. I have a **Illnesses** table with columns **percent**, **illness**, **date**.

```
SELECT I.percent, I.illness, I.date
FROM Illnesses I
INNER JOIN Person P on I.person_id = P.id  // an inner join I use in where clause
WHERE P.id = someId    //  13 let's say
```

So in my case for Person with id = 13 query'll return

```
51, someIllness, 2015-12-07
43,someOtherIllness, 2015-12-08
null, anotherIllness, 2015-12-08
```

I need to select the row where **date** is most recent, and highest **percent** if there are multiple rows with that date. I added the following code in where clause

```
AND I.date = (SELECT max(I2.date)
FROM Illnesess I2
INNER JOIN Person P2 on I2.person_id = P2.id
WHERE P2.id = P.id)
AND I.percent = (SELECT max(I2.percent)
FROM Illnesess I2
INNER JOIN Person P2 on I2.person_id = P2.id
WHERE P2.id = P.id AND I2.date = I.date)
```

This will return **43,someOtherIllness, 2015-12-08** and will work fine at least I think so. There is an Exception I need to cover, if for the most recent date percent is **null** I need to take the row with previous date that have percent.

```
51, someIllness, 2015-12-07
null,someOtherIllness, 2015-12-08
null, anotherIllness, 2015-12-08
```

**51, someIllness, 2015-12-07 will be the result I need.**

If anyone help I'll be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using postgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

If you will remove from the start all the Illnesses that has no percent yet?

```
SELECT I.percent, I.illness, I.date
FROM Illnesses I
INNER JOIN Person P on I.person_id = P.id  // an inner join I use in where clause
WHERE P.id = someId
AND I.percent IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT I.percent, I.illness, I.date 
FROM Illnesses I
INNER JOIN Person P on I.person_id = P.id
WHERE I.percent IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY I.date, I.percent DESC
LIMIT 1
```

if you want it to be sort by the highest percent first you can try exchanging the date and percent place in the order by